# Image.Save crashing: {"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: encoder"}

Tags: c#, .net

I have a report that is ran and then rotates images according to their orientation before re-uploading them to Azure Blob Storage.

Below is the code:

```cs
private void ReplaceImageIfRotated(string imgFileName, int imgID)
{
    byte[] imageData = ImgDB.GetImageByID(imgID);

    using (MemoryStream originalStream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    using (MemoryStream correctedStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Image img = Image.FromStream(originalStream);
        bool needsRotation = false;

        if (Array.Exists(img.PropertyIdList, id => id == ExifOrientationId))
        {
            var prop = img.GetPropertyItem(ExifOrientationId);
            int orientationValue = prop.Value[0];

            RotateFlipType rotateFlip = GetRotateFlipTypeFromExif(orientationValue);
            if (rotateFlip != RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone)
            {
                needsRotation = true;
                img.RotateFlip(rotateFlip);

                // Reset orientation to 1 (normal)
                prop.Value[0] = 1;
                img.SetPropertyItem(prop);
            }
        }

        if (needsRotation)
        {
            ImageFormat format = img.RawFormat;
            img.Save(correctedStream, format); // ERRORS OUT HERE
            correctedStream.Position = 0;


            // Replace the image in Azure Blob Storage
            ImgDB.UploadImage(imgFileName, correctedStream);
        }

        img.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The images that will be processed will only be of file type: .jpg, .jpeg, .png, and .tiff.

How can I ensure that when re-saving them, I can save them with their original format?

Comment: Well  img.RawFormat keeps the original format and I see u are passing it as param to Save. So if the Save method is build well the format should be preserved.

Comment: The .Save method is a built-in method frmo System.Drawing. It should technically work as is, i'm unsure why it's erroring out.

The value of format is:

{[ImageFormat: b96b3caa-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e]}

Comment: If you get to see a Guid as format it typically means its something not build into .Net. And for an unknown format its easy to deduce that there is no encoder for that. Take a look at the Encoders returned by `ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()` and see if your Guid is mentioned (the FormatId).

Comment: Does your code above crash for all types of images? Or just for some of them?

Comment: That Guids is MemoryBmp and .Net should actually know about. MemoryBmp can't be saved you need to use a different format. You might want to check why its a MemoryBmp and not one of your mentioned formats. Why ImgDB.GetImageByID delivers what it delivers.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, occurs when you're trying to save an image using `img.Save` without specifying the correct image encoder for the image format.

```
private void ReplaceImageIfRotated(string imgFileName, int imgID)
{
    byte[] imageData = ImgDB.GetImageByID(imgID);

    using (MemoryStream originalStream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    using (MemoryStream correctedStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Image img = Image.FromStream(originalStream);
        bool needsRotation = false;

        if (Array.Exists(img.PropertyIdList, id => id == ExifOrientationId))
        {
            var prop = img.GetPropertyItem(ExifOrientationId);
            int orientationValue = prop.Value[0];

            RotateFlipType rotateFlip = GetRotateFlipTypeFromExif(orientationValue);
            if (rotateFlip != RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone)
            {
                needsRotation = true;
                img.RotateFlip(rotateFlip);

                // Reset orientation to 1 (normal)
                prop.Value[0] = 1;
                img.SetPropertyItem(prop);
            }
        }

        if (needsRotation)
        {
            ImageCodecInfo codecInfo = GetEncoderInfo(img.RawFormat);

            if (codecInfo != null)
            {
                img.Save(correctedStream, codecInfo, null);
                correctedStream.Position = 0;

                // Replace the image in Azure Blob Storage
                ImgDB.UploadImage(imgFileName, correctedStream);
            }
        }

        img.Dispose();
    }
}

private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat format)
{
    ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
    return codecs.FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == format.Guid);
}
```